# Favorite tool for word/phrase counting

Tags: full-text-search, text-mining, data-analysis, word-count, text-analysis

I am looking for a tool that performs counting of words and, more importantly, phrases, in large amounts of open-ended text responses.  I need the ability to exclude certain words (a, the, and, etc.) as well.

I am aware of a few tools that do this:

```
 - http://www.mywritertools.com/default.asp
 - http://www.hermetic.ch/wfca/wfca.htm
```

As well as some lists of available text mining software

```
 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_text_mining_software
 - http://academic.csuohio.edu/kneuendorf/content/cpuca/qtap.htm
 - http://www.predictiveanalyticstoday.com/top-30-software-for-text-analysis-text-mining-text-analytics/
```

Most of these either a) cost money, or b) provide much more/different functionality than I need.  I am not opposed to paying a moderate amount (< $100) for a decent tool, but am hoping to get some input first to avoid buying something that doesn't meet my needs.

**Data specifics:**
1) currently resides in a SQL database, but can transformed into whatever format needed (text file, excel, whatever)
2) contains  an opened ended response, and a category id relating to a specific product or type of product (eg. either "soda" or "pepsi")

**Needs**
1) Ability to count common words and phrases
2) Ability to exclude a list of words (a, the, and, etc.) such that "wash car" and "wash **the** car" would count as the same phrase

**Would be nice to have**
1) Ability to match based on root word so that "**wash** the car", "**washed** the car" and "**washes** the car" all match
2) Ability to see what words appear near each other so that I can get a count of the times that "wash car", "wash the car" and "car wash" appear as a single count.

**Icing on the cake**
1) Ability to do counts based on categories.  Not a big deal as the number of categories is relatively low and I can run each individually, but this may change in the future.

Please share any advice/experience/suggestions!  Also, I am not opposed to writing my own tool, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.  In the absence of a specific tool, any libraries that may assist in doing this (especially for root word matching), would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it doesn't look like this is something anyone else really needs, but just in case, here's how I solved my problem.

I used 2 different tools:

- Hermetic Word Frequency Advanced (http://www.hermetic.ch/wfca/wfca.htm)
- RapidMiner Studio (https://rapidminer.com/) with the Text Processing extension added through RapidMiner Marketplace

The RapidMiner text processing tools worked great for extracting json, segmenting data, extracting relevant data, and then tokenizing/normalizing and removing common words prior to the actual processing I needed to do.  It also allowed the creation of n-grams, and then word frequency analysis including n-grams.  Very cool tool that has a lot more possibilities.

Since the requirements for this specific project wanted ONLY a list of phrases with their frequencies (Could have extracted this from the output of the RapidMiner word frequency analysis but would have required some manual work), I also employed the use of the Hermetic Word Frequency Advanced (HWFA) tool, which allowed for the counting of only phrases.

After pre-processing the text using RapidMiner (tokenizing, making all lowercase, removing common words, stemming), I took that output and ran it through (HWFA) to get exactly what I wanted.  I was surprised with as powerful as RapidMiner is that it wasn't possible to get only phrases back with their frequencies, but if it is possible (which it might be - the tool is pretty powerful), my 3 days of toying with it didn't uncover how.

RapidMiner Studio Basic and the Text Mining extension are both free.  HWFA was $60 (overpriced if you ask me, but did the trick in a pinch).

Hope this may be able to help someone else some day!